# Listview builder scroll list automatically when inserting data - flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart, mobile, scroll

I am developing one chat app and I am adding data to chatList which is the list of model and I am getting the newest data from the backend like when I call API it will give the last message so I need to get data from pagination without using any lazy loading method or something so for that I need to call API when I get data to get more data and my list is reverse list (I have UI different so I can't use reverse property in listview) so I need to insert data to first index like this `list.insertAll(0,data)` but when I do that my list is automatically scrolled but when I use `list.add()` it is not automatically scrolling.

I have tried most of the methods and scroll physics even I have made one custom scroll physics which remains scroll when inserting data but nothing works in my project I have created on demo project and it is working in that.

Comment: Can you check the answer I added?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using the magic `ScrollController` and `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` , I made an example for you:

Results:

[image]

Code:

```dart
class ChatHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatHome({super.key});

  @override
  State<ChatHome> createState() => _ChatHomeState();
}

class _ChatHomeState extends State<ChatHome> {
  final list = List.generate(
    20,
    (index) => 'Message $index',
  );

  final controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              final initialMaxScrollExtent =
                  controller.position.maxScrollExtent;
              setState(() {
                final message = 'Message ${list.length}';
                list.insert(0, message);
              });
              WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                final difference = controller.position.maxScrollExtent -
                    initialMaxScrollExtent;
                controller.jumpTo(controller.offset + difference);
              });
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list.length,
        controller: controller,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(
              list[index],
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks diegoveloper This works for me but this is giving me scrolling effect and also when I start scrolling it will scroll to bottom when fetching the data, I have 10000 data so it dosen't work with that.

Comment: If possible can you add timer and call in initstate and add data using list.insert and then tell me if it works or not

Comment: it shouldn't scroll if you use "controller.jumpTo" , are you using animateTo?

Comment: Here is example of what is happening in my app
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R295cVKy0IAB-zHC_Z6xQnoustINgYHa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I am using jump to, I have one column and in that wrap my Listview.builder with Expanded

Comment: hmm maybe it's something wrong with your widget distributions, it seems it's scrolling more than what it needs, you should check what's the offset.

Comment: Even if I jump to scrollController.offset then also it is scrolling to current offset after inserting data

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following?

Add this Scrollcontroller to your widget.

```
final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
```

Add the controller to your ListView (or whatever you use)

```
return ListView.builder(
                  controller: _scrollController, //add this line
...
```

Lets first try with a button.

```
IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
                    final position =
                        _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent; //or minScrollExtent
                    _scrollController.animateTo(
                      position,
                      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                    );
                  }
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward))
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts brill, but unfortunately this is not something which I am looking for I don't want to scroll to bottom but listview scrolling it automatically when I am inserting data to listview which is already exist and rendered on screen

Answer (score 1):

Just try to add Controller with "keepScrollOffset" property see if it works.
Example

```
ScrollController controller = ScrollController(keepScrollOffset: true);

ListView.builder(
  controller: controller
  reverse: true, 
  itemBuilder: .....
);
```

Use this statement while adding data to list

```
controller .jumpTo(0.0); 
list.insertAll(0, newData);
```